# Bad user name error in Xampp for mac

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, xampp, localhost

Suddenly, the apache and MySQL won't start anymore. I already restarted the mac several times, but the error persists:

Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
apache config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
AH00543: httpd: bad user name lucasvallim

I didn't change any configuration at all, it was running normally but then this error appeared...

Any suggestions?